# How to call method in inner class using java?

Tags: java

Can you call method in inner class without calling constructor in class `A` this my code:

```
public class A {

    public A() {
        System.out.println("You are in Class A");
    }

    public class innerA {

        public innerA() {
            System.out.println("You Are in Class InnerA");
        }

        public void PrintName() {
            System.out.println("Jack in InnerA");
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    A.innerA obj = new A().new innerA();
}
```

Comment: No you can’t, by definition an inner class needs an instance of an outer class and creating an instance always invokes the constructor. [barring esoteric cases like deserialization and cloning]

Comment: An inner class is part of the instance, a static nested class is just part of the class. This is the same as a member, you can't access a variable without creating an instance first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you need an *instance* of `InnerA` to actually call a method on it and in your case you can't do that because you would *also* need an instance of `A` for that.

You could change the declaration to:

```
static public class InnerA {...}
```

thus not needing an instance of `A`, only an instance of `InnerA`

Comment: Hey did you also think about making InnerA and the wanted method static?

Comment: But it would no longer be an inner class (it would be a static member class)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt ah, I didin't know there was a diffrence :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Car { 
       void carMethod() { 

          System.out.println("inside carMethod"); 
          class TataCar { 
             void tataCarMethod() { 
                System.out.println("inside tataCarMethod"); 
             } 
          } 
          TataCar y = new TataCar(); 
          y.tataCarMethod(); 
       } 
    } 
    class MainClass { 
       public static void main(String[] args) { 
          Car carObj=new Car(); 
          carObj.carMethod(); 
       } 
    }


    Output:
    inside carMethod
    inside tataCarMethod
```